# How to access a zip file into a zip file in Java

Tags: java, zip

I'm trying to read .srt files that are located in zip file itself located in a zip file. I succeed to read .srt files that were in a simple zip with the extract of code below :

```
    for (Enumeration enume = fis.entries(); enume.hasMoreElements();) {
                ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) enume.nextElement();
                fileName = entry.toString().substring(0,entry.toString().length()-4);
try {
                    InputStream in = fis.getInputStream(entry);
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String ext = entry.toString().substring(entry.toString().length()-4, entry.toString().length());
```

But now i don't know how i could get to the zip file inside the zip file.
I tried using ZipFile fis = new ZipFile(filePath) with filePath being the path of the zip file + the name of zip file inside. It didn't recognize the path so i don't know if i am clear.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to scan for the file or can you determine an explicit path? If you have a path, I think you can use an URL for that.

Comment: I have to scan the zip file to know the path of the file that is inside. I don't know what are the names of the files inside the zip file before scanning it.

Comment: Wrap each qualifying entry in a new [ZipInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html).

Comment: I think this is what i need, i will look into it, i am not sure how to use it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

`ZipFile` only works with real files, because it's intended for use as a random access mechanism which needs to be able to seek directly to specific locations in the file to read entries by name.  But as VGR suggests in the comments, while you can't get *random* access to the zip-inside-a-zip you *can* use `ZipInputStream`, which provides strictly sequential access to the entries and works with any `InputStream` of zip-format data.

However, `ZipInputStream` has a slightly odd usage pattern compared to other streams - calling `getNextEntry` reads the entry metadata and positions the stream to read that entry's data, you read from the `ZipInputStream` until it reports EOF, then you (optionally) call `closeEntry()` before moving on to the next entry in the stream.

The critical point is that you *must not* `close()` the `ZipInputStream` until you have finished reading the final entry, so depending what you want to do with the entry data you might need to use something like the [commons-io `CloseShieldInputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/input/CloseShieldInputStream.html) to guard against the stream getting closed prematurely.

```
try(ZipInputStream outerZip = new ZipInputStream(fis)) {
  ZipEntry outerEntry = null;
  while((outerEntry = outerZip.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    if(outerEntry.getName().endsWith(".zip")) {
      try(ZipInputStream innerZip = new ZipInputStream(
                  new CloseShieldInputStream(outerZip))) {
        ZipEntry innerEntry = null;
        while((innerEntry = innerZip.getNextEntry()) != null) {
          if(innerEntry.getName().endsWith(".srt")) {
            // read the data from the innerZip stream
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to make it recursive because it might be possible that there is a zip file in a zip file in a zip file etc ...

Comment: *"read the data from the innerZip stream"*  could someone kindly point me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Find the code to extract .zip files recursively:

```
public void extractFolder(String zipFile) throws ZipException, IOException {
System.out.println(zipFile);
int BUFFER = 2048;
File file = new File(zipFile);

ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(file);
String newPath = zipFile.substring(0, zipFile.length() - 4);

new File(newPath).mkdir();
Enumeration zipFileEntries = zip.entries();

// Process each entry
while (zipFileEntries.hasMoreElements())
{
    // grab a zip file entry
    ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) zipFileEntries.nextElement();
    String currentEntry = entry.getName();
    File destFile = new File(newPath, currentEntry);
    //destFile = new File(newPath, destFile.getName());
    File destinationParent = destFile.getParentFile();

    // create the parent directory structure if needed
    destinationParent.mkdirs();

    if (!entry.isDirectory())
    {
        BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(zip
        .getInputStream(entry));
        int currentByte;
        // establish buffer for writing file
        byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

        // write the current file to disk
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
        BufferedOutputStream dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos,
        BUFFER);

        // read and write until last byte is encountered
        while ((currentByte = is.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
            dest.write(data, 0, currentByte);
        }
        dest.flush();
        dest.close();
        is.close();
    }

    if (currentEntry.endsWith(".zip"))
    {
        // found a zip file, try to open
        extractFolder(destFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This method will extract everything that is in the zip file and create a folder to put everything in it if i understand. I was looking for something that wouldn't have to extract and that could read the files that are in the zip file. If there is no other solution, i will take this.

Comment: You can modify the some part of the code to access the zipfile inside a zipfile:

    `if (currentEntry.endsWith(".zip"))
    {
        // found a zip file, try to read
        // write a read .zip code here.
    }`